# how to run 2 connected classes in java on cmd?

Tags: java, class

So I need to write a program in java that takes 2 user inputed temperatures in celsius and converts it to Fahrenheit and kelvin. i wrote the code and it works in eclipse but my teacher strictly said it has to work in cmd. it compiles fine but when i go to run it it states `could not find or load main class temperatureTester` (name of the class with my main). This is my first post so if you need more info please ask and i'm looking for any ideas why this is happening. below is my code for the question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class temperatureTester{

    public static void main (String[]args){

    //create 2 objects connecting to temperatureC
    temperatureC firstValue = new temperatureC();
    temperatureC secondValue = new temperatureC();
    // initialize scanner
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);
    //initialize variables
    double firstC = 0;
    double secondC = 0;
    //prompt user for both values
    System.out.print("Please enter initial temperatures: ");
    firstC = stdin.nextDouble();
    secondC = stdin.nextDouble();
    //call object set methods and pass entered values as arguments
    firstValue.setC(firstC);
    secondValue.setC(secondC);
    //display the values for the values for different temp. units
    System.out.println("1) The current temperature in Celcius is: " + firstValue.getC());
    System.out.println("1) The current temperature in fahreinheit is: " + firstValue.getF());
    System.out.println("1) The current temperature in kelvin is: " + firstValue.getK());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("2) The current temperature in Celcius is: " + secondValue.getC());
    System.out.println("2) The current temperature in fahreinheit is: " + secondValue.getF());
    System.out.println("2) The current temperature in kelvin is: " + secondValue.getK());
```

this is the second  class

```
public class temperatureC{

private double C;

/**
 The setC method stores the value in the C field

 @ param initialC the value stored in C
*/

public void setC(double initialC){
    C = initialC;
}

/**
 The getC returns the C value and also sets a lower limit,
 if a number below is entered it sets it ti the limit.

 @Return the value of the C 
*/
public double getC(){

    if(C < -273.15){
        C = -273.15;
    }

    return C;
}

/**
 the getF method calculates and returns a value for C in fahrenheit

 @return the computed for C in fahrenheit 
*/
public double getF(){

    return C * 1.8 + 32;
}

/**
 The getK method computes and returns a value for temperature C in kelvin 

 @return the computed Kelvin value
*/
public double getK(){

    return C + 273.15;
}
}
```

Comment: how are you running it ? can you post your commands?

Comment: Please note that Java classes should start with `CapitalLetters`

Answer (score 0):

The Best approach might b that you export your project as executable jar file to achieve this have a look on following official ecclipse link http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

then next part you need to run it from Command line this is a fun part just change the directory to the path where your jar file is located and then here comes the following command

```
java -jar yourJar.jar
pause
```

and then it will b executing like a charm!

Comment: I think he should compile and run in cmd rather than exporting it to jar and run it in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compile your both files in cmd using `javac`
After successfully compiling simply run your main class i.e **temperatureTester** class using `java`. It successfully executed.

[image]